# Using logarithmic differentiation to find the derivative of the function $y=x^{x+1}(x+1)^x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

> Using logarithmic differentiation, find the derivative of the function $y=x^{x+1}(x+1)^x$.

I knew one may begin with this step.
$$\ln(y)=\ln(x^{x+1})+\ln(x+1)^x$$
But how to differentiate this?

Comment: Is there a question there? Did you perhaps want to take the derivative of $y$? Or something similar?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't memtion it. Actuallt, the question is using logarithmic differentiation to find the derivative of the giving function.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Knowing this will help us tailor the answer to be helpful to you.

Comment: Note that $\ln(x^{x+1})=(x+1)\ln x$ and that the second part of the right hand can be transformed using the same property ($\ln A^B=B\ln A$). These two transformations will not simplify the expression, but will simplify the differentiation, bringing it to the use of the derivative of a sum and two products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ln(y)=ln(x^{x+1})+ln((x+1)^x)=(x+1)ln(x)+xln(x+1)$ by logarithm rules. Then you can just use the product rule to finish it up

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually know how to do it yesterday!